# Cycling peak load trips genset

Tags: capacitor, load

I have an application where a cycling peak load from a 40hp motor is regularly tripping a 65Kw genset. Here are the details of the configuration:

- 65Kw Genset powered by a natural gas engine
- 40hp pump jack motor is the primary load
- the peak load cycles from 100% load to 0% load in 5-6 second, then back to 100%
- There are a few auxiliary loads being added, such as heat tracking and lighting.
- There is a VFD in line between the generator and motor.

When the load initiates it goes to 100% immediately, continues for 3-5 seconds, then dumps to 0% load ( actually due to a counterbalance system it tries to backfeed, a sink is used to prevent the backfeed to generator). This cycle has caused no problems previously at lower speeds, but at the current operating speed the cycles are too short for the engine controls to react and increase work to make up for the load changes. Slowing down the motor is not an option.

A similar situation we are/will encounter is where we have 3-5 motors under the same load circumstances running at one site, though the loads are not synced, they are all at different cycle speeds meaning eventually the peak load across all motors will sync, likely resulting in a generator trip.

To help determine solutions I'll rule out the following possibilities:

- Simply increasing power supply is a tough sell, although ideal for my interests I would need to be able to prove absolutely it is the only option.
- We have no control over what speeds the motors are operated at.
- Our genset sizes are calculated by our customer and requested as such, they are very stubborn and confident in their calculations.

We are performing full site load calcs in the coming days but this is a very time sensitive issue so I'm pulling on all my sources now, any help is greatly appreciated. There are two options I have come up with already but need further confirmation to act on either of them. They are:

- Install a capacitor between the generator and VFD/Motor to act as a buffer, lowering the immediate draw on the generator as well as the immediate drop of load.
- Install more or a larger genset, this requires absolute proof for the electrical engineers that they are wrong, likely more challenging then inventing my own superconductor.

Comment: Can you program the VFD to soft start the motor - ramp it up to speed over a couple more seconds?

Comment: That would work, except I missed another point about the configuration, we can't change anything about how the load is physically applied. it is 0% to 100% instantly, then 100% to 0% instantly with a very high inertia load. The customer expects to be able to run the load as fast as mechanically possible, with no consideration for electrical limits.

Comment: *"Our genset sizes are calculated by our customer and requested as such, they are very stubborn and confident in their calculations."* Are they verifying their calculations with actual power measurements? Can they show that the gensets are not meeting their specs? If not, then it's their problem, not yours. In the meantime, maybe you should be taking some measurements of your own to (hopefully) demonstrate that the gensets *are* meeting their specs.

Comment: Are you applying the load by starting the motor from rest, or by something like a clutch to a running motor? In the first case you MUST soft start - or rate the genset and VFD for starting current (maybe 5x running current) which is uneconomical. In the second case, you may just need a bigger flywheel. Possibly on a separate 3-phase motor where it will act as a generator during sudden loads. (This may answer the second, multi-motor, case)

Comment: Thank you Dave Tweed, I believe the problem is they are sizing the required generator based solely on the size of the motor, not taking into account the type of load on the motor, the VFD, or the auxiliary equipment they keep patching into the circuit. What makes it my problem is them insisting that the issue is our product itself, not the sizing of the generator.

Comment: We are in the process currently of load mapping and calculating this site and several like it, so far it is looking like with a little "mathing" we will be able to show indisputably that they simply need a larger generator or PMG, as for a capacitor bank, that is looking more and more infeasible every minute.

Comment: Brian Drummond, thank you for your reply. The load is essentially applied from rest, every 5-6 seconds. The motor rotates for have a rotation with full load, then half a rotation with 0 load. I have found that in that case you must account for 300% to 600% running current, adding a VFD doesn't help any either. From my rough calculations without a detailed load map, a 65Kw Generator can't reliably run a 40HP high inertia loaded motor with a VFD without any aux equipment or accounting for voltage dip due to the line or generator.

Comment: Is the motor running continuously and the load being connected and disconnected with a mechanical or hydraulic clutch?  Or does the motor stop and start each time?